# How to best display Data Graphically

Tags: website-design

Ok, so i am working on an App and it is for health care and progress tracking. We have different areas where are tracking information:

- **Exercise** - track how often a user exercises
- **Eating** - how often the user eats
- **Wellbeing** - the user will complete 10 questions per day
- **Medical Data** - this will be a long list of how they are performing e.g. cholestrol levels, hormone levels, psa levels (about 20 different stats)

I thought it would be good because this is all in one page, to toggle the information or add icons - which they would click through to the information. The top two are simple graphs/chart. Wellbeing would also be a series of charts. However having 20+ charts for Medical data i think is too much - but would a simple list be boring. Also there is a lot of information.

Any thoughts would be great

Answer (score 1):

From how I interpret your question, you want to know how to display a summary of the **medical data** in a way that is not "boring" or overloading.

Perhaps you could have a grid of mini-charts that have show a graph, have a unique color and label, which (when clicked / pressed on) will open up another view that shows the details of the graph and more data.

As a *secondary* suggestion, what if you arranged the labels onto a relevant graphic (like an outline of a person or certain organs?) that can be clicked. The graphic would have to be large, because of the amount of data you have.

**The key point** is that I think you should implement a sort of master-detail view with graphics that uniquely suit your application.